# pd.categorical didn't sort bars by specified orders in plot

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to use pd categorical to order the bars in a barplot but the result still didn't get sorted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(1,10,15),'y': ['x']*15})
df.loc[:,'group'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x:'>=5' if x>=5 else x)
df['group'] = df['group'].astype('string')
sample = df['group'].value_counts().reset_index()
sample['index'] =  pd.Categorical(sample['index'],categories=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','>=5'], ordered=True)
sample.plot(x='index',kind='bar')
```

After applied ordered=True, the categories still weren't in order and '>=5' were not at the end of the barplot. Not sure why.

Comment: you can try with sample.sort_values('group').plot(x='index',kind='bar')

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.plot.bar()` plots the bars in order of occurrence (that is, against the range) and relabel the ticks with the column specified by `x`.

This is the case even with numerical data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'idx': [3,2,1], 'val':[4,5,6]}).plot.bar(x='idx')
```

would give:

[image]

In your case, you will need to sort the data before plot:

```
sample.sort_values('index').plot(x='index',kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: that's very helpful, but what if i need a custom order rather than sort by occurrence?

Comment: by occurrence, I mean the order that data appear in the dataframe. Basically, it plot row 0 at tick 0, row 1 at tick 1, and so on. Then it relabel tick 0 as `df['x'].iloc[0]` and so on.